# Google Cloud Function Not able to delete Bigquery Dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I have created a cloud function which will list down all Bigquery datasets which are falling under certain criteria, and then delete all such Bigquery datasets.
I am using following Delete API request :-

```
bigquery_client.delete_dataset(
dataset['schema_name'], delete_contents=True, not_found_ok=True
)  # Make an API request.
```

its giving following error:-

```
fn_clean_bq_datasetrrhier7sk4oz Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args) 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 99, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object()) File "/workspace/main.py", line 76, in clean_bq_dataset bigquery_client.delete_dataset( 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 1571, in delete_dataset self._call_api( File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 759, in _call_api return call() 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func return retry_target( File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 190, in retry_target return target() 
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/_http/__init__.py", line 494, in api_request raise exceptions.from_http_response(response) google.api_core.exceptions.
Forbidden: 403 DELETE https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/xxxxxxxx/datasets/dataset_v05c248634?deleteContents=true&prettyPrint=false: Access Denied: Dataset xxxxxxxxx:dataset_v05c248634: Permission bigquery.datasets.delete denied on dataset xxxxxxxxxxx:dataset_v05c248634 (or it may not exist).
```

Please suggest what permissions are missing here on Google cloud function.

Comment: Fyi your question literally contains the answer :`permission bigquery.datasets.delete denied`.  (and if you fixed that one you would see the other one)

Comment: How to add permission at Cloud Function. I have created a service account with these roles, how to associate service account to Cloud Function.

Comment: Hi @VibhorGupta, Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have parked Problem till i find a solution.

Comment: By default cloud functions will use App Engine default service account, can you check whether the service account linked is having these required [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bq-permissions) and `cloudfunctions.serviceAgent` role.

Answer (score 0):

[Required permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets?authuser=2#required_permissions)

To delete a dataset, you need the following IAM permissions:

```
bigquery.datasets.delete (lets you delete a dataset)
bigquery.tables.delete (lets you delete tables and views)
```

Each of the following predefined IAM roles includes the permissions that you need in order to delete a dataset:

```
roles/bigquery.dataOwner
roles/bigquery.admin
```

Additionally, if you have the bigquery.datasets.create permission, you can delete the datasets and tables that you create.

Comment: How to add permission at Cloud Function. I have created a service account with these roles, how to associate service account to Cloud Function.

Comment: Cloud Functions use the App Engine default service account https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/services#using_services_with_cloud_functions